# Android softkeyboard turn on caps lock after symbol

Tags: android

I have an edit text field. Edit text has created with invisible symbol, for example '#' - invisible symbol. When user clicks on EditText, it shows small letters on the virtual keyboard.

I want that after invisible symbol first letter caps and rest of them small on the keyboard.

How can this be done?

Comment: `Edit text has created with invisible symbol` what it mean by?

Comment: I think, he is initializing # at the first letter. why cant you add # dynamically when you take the value in java side??

Comment: shylendra,
EditText mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(...);
mEditText.setText('#');
And user can input only after this symbol.
Jithu, 
Because # is new symbol of new paragraph. It need to correct apply ParagraphSpans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I founded the solution. I solved this problem via InputType. It's bad, but nothing better I didn't find. 
In CustomEditText you should override method onSelectionChanged and change InputType there:

```
public boolean isWasCap = false;// Was capitalisation turn on?

public void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    ...

    setCap();
}

/**
 * Method check is need turn on capitalization
 */
private void setCap(){
    int start = getSelectionStart();
    int end = getSelectionEnd();
    if (start == end && start > 0
            && getText().charAt(start-1) == INVISIBLE_SYMBOL) {
        if(isWasCap) // Capitalization is turn on 
            return;
        setInputMask(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES, InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
        isWasCap = true;
    }else if(isWasCap){
        isWasCap = false;
        setInputMask(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS, InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
    }
}

/**
 * Method replace one input type to other input type
 * @param needRemove - mask which will remove
 * @param needSetup - masr which will setup
 */
public void setInputMask(int needRemove, int needSetup){
    int mask = getInputType() & ~needRemove;
    mask = mask | needSetup;
    setInputType(mask);
}
```

style.xml

```
<style name="Common.Editor">

   <item name="android:inputType">textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect</item>
</style>
```

main_activity.xml

```
 <com.view.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Common.Editor"
        />
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed and works like a charm. However I simplified the code quite a bit:int inputType = getInputType();
   if (selStart <= 1) {
      setInputType(inputType | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
   } else {
      setInputType(inputType & ~InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
   }

Comment: @Ridcully  I must warn you, that this solve haves some defects: 
1) If user input text by swiping, all text which will be pasted to EditTtext will be witten with capital latters. It need monitoring inside TextWatcher.
2) Word which will be entered will work different way in autocomplete on different devices. One won't autocomplete this word, another will autocomplete word without first later, another will autocomplete correct.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. How did you implement TextWatcher then? Is this why you have the isWasCap variable?

Comment: @Ridcully isWasCap needs for case where user had selected first position(and we had turned on capitalization) and after that he will select this position one more time (or will select another paragraph where need to turn on capitalization) capitalization won't be turned on because it was turned on before. Also it needs for turn off capitalization, if user changes cursor position and isWasCap == true, capitalization will turn off.

Comment: Hi Dima, after digging in the Android source code, I found a very simple solution, possibly also usable by you: The decision whether to turn caps on or off goes all the way down to the method `TextUtils.getCapsMode(CharSequence cs, int off, int reqModes)` and this method skips the characters " and ' before making a decision. So if you use one of those characters (instead of your #) the capitalization just works, also with swyping and all. No need to fiddle with the InputType or anything.

Comment: @Ridcully TextUtils.getCapsMode - "Returns the actual capitalization modes that can be in effect at the current position". But it doesn't change cap mode and after calling that method, I will need to change inputtype by myself, and this action generates problem with swiping and autocompletion. If I understood something wrong, please tell me.

Comment: What I meant is - if you change your # to a ", you can remove your setCap() method altogether and it will still work. Just try in a regular empty EditText field (e.g. Gmail-App). If you enter ", the keyboard will still be in Caps mode.

Comment: @Ridcully yes it will. But it android ignores this symbol. Also in release I change '#' to item which user cannot enter by keyboard.

Comment: I see. I had an 'invisible space' unicode character for that part, but now switched it to a simple quote which I make invisible using a Span of transparent color. Also in my case I have that character only at the very beginning of a text and also tweaked the EditText so that user cannot move the cursor there.

Answer (score 0):

simply  Set `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` on your EditText.

OR

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

Comment: I think, he is initialising # at the first letter. So this may not work.