# SoftKeyboard, invalidateAllKeys() doesn't seem to do nothing

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an app with a KeyboardView that contains a qwerty keyboard.In it along with the letters i have a caps key.

In my java i have the switch to check which key was pressed, and in one of the cases i have this one:

```
//...
case -5:
 caps = !caps;
 keyboard.setShifted(caps); //Keyboard
 qwerty_keyboard.invalidateAllKeys(); //KeyboardView
 qwerty_keyboard.requestLayout();
 break;
default:
 char code = (char) primaryCode;
 if (Character.isLetter(code) && caps) {
  code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
 }
 et_search.getText().append(code);
 break;
 //...
```

the default part works well and writes the letters in lower or uppercase.
The only thing that ins't working is the invalidateAllKeys(), that doesn't change the Keys in the keyboardView to uppercase.

Do i need to do something else?

**Edit**
this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="1dp"
    android:verticalGap="1dp"
    android:keyHeight="36dp"
    >

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template"
            android:popupCharacters="éê"/>
        <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
        <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
        <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
        <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template"
            android:popupCharacters="ú"/>
        <Key android:codes="105,237" android:keyLabel="i" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template"
            android:popupCharacters="í"/>
        <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template"
            android:popupCharacters="òóôõ"/>
        <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:horizontalGap="5%p"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template"
            android:popupCharacters="àáâã"/>
        <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
        <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
        <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
        <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
        <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
        <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
        <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="Shift"
            android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:isRepeatable="true" />
        <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="z"/>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
        <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="c" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template"
            android:popupCharacters="ç"/>
        <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="v"/>
        <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="b"/>
        <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="n"/>
        <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="m"/>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyIcon="@drawable/undo"
            android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    </Row>

    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE"
            android:keyWidth="50%p" android:isRepeatable="true" android:horizontalGap="15%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="-2" android:keyLabel="Hide"
            android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Comment: is your switch loop accepting keyboard constant? like -5 means KEYCODE_DELETE

Comment: yeah i changed the xml, i've added a piece of the XML to the question

Comment: so when user press delete key on qwerty, it goes to case -5 and enable/disable caps lock state and redraw layout by calling invalidateallkeys() and requestlayout(). am i right?

Comment: The user presses the key and it enters in that case, yes (in my keyboard.xml, - 5 is the shift or caps)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328395/android-softkeyboard-turn-on-caps-lock-after-symbol) post might help you answer your question.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your keyboard xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (primaryCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            /*ic.deleteSurroundingText(1,0);*/

            CharSequence selectedText = ic.getSelectedText(0);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
                ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            } else {
                ic.commitText("", 1);
            }
            break;

        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            isCaps = !isCaps;
            keyboard_one.setShifted(isCaps);
            keyboard_view.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;

        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;

        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && isCaps)
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
    }

}
```

try this :)